# Bootstrap thank you modal shows when there is a cookie, different thank you modal shows when no cookie

Tags: cookies, bootstrap-modal

I have three modals, one is a form, the other two are thank you messages that one needs to show by using a cookie and the other when there is no cookie. I am using jquery for this. Any help is appreciated